# Using a postinstall script with npm

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, bower

I am using the following in packages.json for postinstall.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false && gulp build"
  },
```

However, the `&&` is not supported in some environments. How can I place the equivalent commands in a `postinstall.js` script, so that I can execute both?